# PHP round time and hours

Tags: php, time, rounding, hour

I need to round some times. I would like to know how I can round a time to the next hour and use that as an int in PHP.

Ex:

```
24:00:02 -> 25  
33:15:05 -> 34  
48:40:30 -> 49
```

Any ideas?

Regards
Claudio

Comment: Assuming that is HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS you've got there, in terms of time duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you handle the time string like a number, PHP treats it like one and removes everyting but the first digits.

```
print '48:40:30' + 1; # 49
print '30:00:00' + 1; # 31
```

Comment: This would work to increment the values by one, but is not "rounding" in any sense of the word - which is what the OP is asking for.  It fails to take in to account the values for minutes and seconds.

Comment: @Chris: From the examples, it is clear that OP wants to `ceil`, not `round`. I used the example of 30:00:00 to make sure that was understood.

Comment: The original examples did ask for this as Tim describes, though all of us scrambled for a 'rounding' solution in the traditional sense.

Answer (score 3):

You'd want something like [DateTime::setTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php). Use the date functions to extract the hours/minutes/seconds, figure out if the hour needs to be incremented, then set the hour to the appropriate value and zero out the minutes and seconds.

hmm. on reading your question again, something like this:

```
$sec = date('s', $timevalue);
$min = date('i', $timevalue);
$hour = date('G', $timevalue);

if (($sec > 0) or ($min > 0)) { $hour++; } // if at x:00:01 or better, "round up" the hour
```

Comment: By far the best answer.  While not necessary I would do `$min = intval(date('i', $timevalue));`  The string to int conversion must be done so the this is the appropriate time.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming the format you're using is HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS, expressing a duration of time rather than a time of day, and I'll assume that you've got this value as a string.  In which case, your solution is a home-brew function, as this is a pretty specific case.  Something like this:

```
function roundDurationUp($duration_string='') {
     $parts = explode(':', $duration_string);
     // only deal with valid duration strings
     if (count($parts) != 3)
       return 0;

     // round the seconds up to minutes
     if ($parts[2] > 30)
       $parts[1]++;

     // round the minutes up to hours
     if ($parts[1] > 30)
       $parts[0]++;

     return $parts[0];
    }

print roundDurationUp('24:00:02'); // prints 25
print roundDurationUp('33:15:05'); // prints 34
print roundDurationUp('48:40:30'); // prints 49
```

Try it: http://codepad.org/nU9tLJGQ

Answer (score 2):

```
function ReformatHourTime($time_str){
                $min_secs = substr($time_str,3);
                $direction = round($min_secs/60);

                if($dir == 1){
                    return $time_str+1;
                }else{
                    return floor($time_str);
                }
         }
```